# How to programmatically add values to a listbox in a worksheet, not on UserForms?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to programmatically add values to a listbox that I inserted inside an Excel worksheet. I've tried searching up for a solution online but all I see are solutions meant for UserForms, not for Worksheets. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of listbox controls you can add to a worksheet.

[image]

With a **Form Control**, the content content is set via the input range, which contains **range** of values in a worksheet. For example:

[image]

If the listbox is an **ActiveX** control, you can refer to it in code via the worksheet that it is placed on, for example:

```
Public Sub UpdateListBox()
   With Sheet1.ListBox1
        .AddItem "A1"
        .AddItem "B2"
        .AddItem "C3"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following codes:

```
Sub AddItemToListBox()
    With Sheet1.ListBox1
        .AddItem "Paris"
        .AddItem "New York"
        .AddItem "London"
    End With
End Sub
```

See these article for more details.

[Article Link 1](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/list-box.html) 
[Article Link 2](https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?2192-Adding-ActiveX-Listbox-set-its-properties-add-items-at-Runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using List Box under Form Controls in a Worksheet, you can manually refresh data given the name of the List Box, you can extend it further to accept input of different datatypes. I am making use of non-intelli collection **ListBoxes** in my code. Note it takes the first name-matched listbox in the workbook.

In a separate Module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshListBox()
    Dim oListBox As ListBox
    Set oListBox = GetListBox("List Box 1")
    If Not oListBox Is Nothing Then
        With oListBox
            .RemoveAllItems ' Clears old items
            .AddItem "Item 1"
            .AddItem "Item 2"
            .AddItem "Item 3"
        End With
    End If
    Set oListBox = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function GetListBox(ListboxName As String) As ListBox
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, oLBox As ListBox
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If oWS.ListBoxes.Count > 0 Then Set oLBox = oWS.ListBoxes(ListboxName)
        If Not oLBox Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next
    Set GetListBox = oLBox
End Function
```